# Salesforce DNS issues

Tags: api

Our use case involves posting data to Salesforce via an external API call for a number of different clients / orgs. By far the majority of the time this works as expected, but sporadically it fails on the DNS level - the DNS lookup will respond with a SERVFAIL result and thus the domain will fail to resolve. There seems to be no pattern in when this occurs - sometimes it may occur several times a day; sometimes it may only occur every few days. (We're doing this in the region of tens of thousands of times a day, so it's a very small percentage - but still rather annoying nonetheless.)

There's also no particular pattern we can see over what servers are affected - we've seen it for both custom domains, and raw servers (eu8, eu11, na63, na65, na48, etc.)

Long story short, over the course of several months we've ruled out everything *other* than the Salesforce DNS servers, and its definitely failing on the DNS resolution level with SERVFAIL each time. In particular, we've tried a number of different DNS servers (Rackspace, Google, OpenDNS) all of which give the same result.

We can of course code in delay / retry logic on the applicatoin controller level, which is something that we'll probably do anyway - but if possible, I'd still like to get to the bottom of what exactly is going on. Is this a known issue, has anyone experienced anything like this before, and if so is there anything that can be done to sort it out?

Comment: I should also clarify that we've submitted a support case with all this detail and more, but we've just had it instantly closed as "Out of scope" each time, since it's classed as a developer question and we don't have premier support.

Comment: We had similar issue, we thought its DNS but it was due to using a fault JAVA http utility library which had this bug.

Secondly , can you check if your access token is valid / or any Platform limits like number of concurrent connections etc coming to your failure.

Comment: Meanwhile, you can tweet this to official salesforce support they will help you resolve or at least escalate it.

Comment: @PranayJaiswal Thanks - what library were you using out of interest? We've looked into the possibility of faulty libraries (also using a Java stack), but a tcpdump definitely shows the requests reaching the DNS level, responding with SERVFAIL, then propogating up the chain back to the Java stack - so the Java stack is doing exactly what it should. We haven't looked in detail at access tokens etc., but I'm not sure that's relevant since if it can't even resolve the domain, it certainly can't get as far as authentication!

Comment: The faulty library was "`org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient`"

Comment: In order to fix it, we used `org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager`

Comment: Hmm, that's interesting as it's definitely the same library we're using, but the fault definitely seems to be on the DNS level. Don't suppose there's a bug report we can examine on the issue?